# Developing Voip Server for Windows with C++

Tags: c++, windows, server, sip, voip

I am extending an application to act as a VOIP server. The application is written in C++, runs on Windows, and will run on a machine with a Dialogic card to connect to the PSTN.

I have been looking at libraries to help me out. Asterisks is one I have looked at, but it doesn't seem to offer good support for Windows and has been difficult to get up and running. Many other VOIP libraries seem to be dead.

Can anyone suggest any free/open source libraries or sample projects that would help me? Please note I am trying to write a server, not just a SIP client so libraries like pjsip won't help much.